# pyodbc.connect() fails on first try to connect to Azure SQL from Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL from an Azure function using pyodbc.connect() with token authentication. The Azure SQL DB has autopause configured. If I call my Azure function after the SQL DB has 'paused', the first try always fails.

I tried adding the the timeout parameter to pyodbc.connect() with timeout=60, but I am still running into errors, e.g.:

```
 ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Database '<DB_NAME>' on server
 '<SERVER_NAME>.database.windows.net' is not currently available. Please retry the connection later. If
 the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of 
'{<TRACKING_ID>}'. (40613) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

How can I ensure that my first call to Azure SQL does not fail?

Comment: As you said, if your database is paused, we can not access it!

Comment: we can not ensure your first call to Azure SQL does not fail it the database has been paused.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. So is the solution to send a connection request initially to wake up the SQL DB (perhaps outside of the Azure function), allowing the remaining Azure function code to run without connection issues?

Comment: yes, you should make the database resume before the Azure Function run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, if your database is paused, we can not access it.

We can not ensure your first call to Azure SQL not fail without know the database status. The idea or solution right, you need send the connection request initially to wake up the SQL DB before you run the Azure Function, then the function can connect to Azure SQL DB without errors.

HTH.